# Multiple Applications using same Zend framework 3 lib

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I've got a few applications running on ZF1, all of them share the same ZF Libs, for the last week I've been studying ZF3 to check if I could update my old apps... For the last 3 days, I've been trying to run multiple applications with the same ZF3 Libs without any luck. I'm new to Zend 3 structure and as far as I can tell it seems that the ZF3 Libs are entangled with the application itself, it seems that I can't run multiple applications using the same lib...

Is it possible and I'm too dumb to figure it out or what I want to do it not possible?

The last test I've made was to crate zend Framework on /var/zf3 and my application was created on /var/www/html/testeApp, I can set the public/index.php to look for the zf3, everything seems to work fine until trying to load the basic Application inside /var/www/html/testeApp/model, its trying to find it inside /var/zf3... I also tried to work with module paths var but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Will vote to close as this is way too broad of a question. However, as some you could [try this online book](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/toc.html). Covers a multitude of topics, from basic routing and form handling to uac & rbac. Should be able to get you started. Make sure to read the comments as it does contain a few mistakes here 'n' there, but they've been pointed out if they've not been fixed yet.

Comment: Application doesn't searches for files, composer loads them. You have to set your autoloader carefully. If you can edit your question and share your psr-4 config, i think we can help.

Comment: I've seen this on ZF1, but I strongly discourage you to use the same practice on ZF3. ZF3 strongly depends on composer to load classes.
Of course, you can create your own autoloader, however I suggest you to keep every application with its own vendor folder. That way, managing app's dependencies would be a lot easier.
And, as suggested by rkeet, take a look on Oleg's book, it is really well written! ;)